# Unknow Char when parsing from text

Tags: android

I am reading one line of text from site. Here is example of what i read:

```
11:28;26.02.12;6.7°C;6.7°C;67;0.7m/s; 6:45;17:40; Warm ;84;0.9;0.0;;
```

And once i read string instead of 6.7°C i get 6.7�C. As it seems this site is not UTF-8 encoding. How should i solve this thath i will make ° instead of � ? Is it possible to solve this at reading, or maybe i can solve this while i am doing string split?

Here is current method i am using for reading from site:

```
public static String getContentFromUrl(String url) throws ClientProtocolException, IOException {

    HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
    HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(url);
    HttpResponse response;

    response = httpClient.execute(httpGet);
    HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();

    if(entity != null) {

        InputStream inStream = entity.getContent();

        String result = Weather.convertStreamToString(inStream);
        inStream.close();

        return result;
    }

    return null;

}

private static String convertStreamToString(InputStream is) {
    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

    String line = null;

    try {
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            sb.append(line + "\n");
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        try {
            is.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    return sb.toString();
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What encoding does the server use? You could try:

```
sb.append((new String(line, "UTF-8")) + "\n");
```

or

```
sb.append((new String(line, "iso-8859-1")) + "\n");
```

Comment: Uhm i should declare this new String at constructor?

Comment: You just place replace one of those lines into the while loop you have.